# ShowWindow/keystrokes only working with notepad

Tags: c#

I'm trying to open the calculator and send keystrokes to it. After doing some research I found some working code for notepad, but when I replace the path to calculator, all it does is open the calculator.

Here is my code. Everything works smoothly, and I played around with the integer in the ShowWindow method to maximize, minimize, etc notepad upon opening.

However, when I use the other path to calculator, it will open calculator and then do nothing. Not only does it refuse to send keystrokes, I cannot seem to minimize it (maximizing calculator doesn't work either way) which means the ShowWindow method isn't working either.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TextSendKeys
{
class Program
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Process notepad = new Process();
        notepad.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:Windows\notepad.exe";
        //notepad.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe";

        notepad.Start();

        // Need to wait for notepad to start
        notepad.WaitForInputIdle();

        IntPtr p = notepad.MainWindowHandle;
        ShowWindow(p, 3);
        SendKeys.SendWait("123");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Using a C# calculator is an alternative. For example [this one](http://programmingnet.weebly.com/world-calculator.html)

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Thanks for the alternative, but I wanna move on to other applications as well so I'd rather have my code working. None of the applications I tried work.